Moving a folder from My Drive to a Shared Drive using Google Drive v3 API and Google App Scripts (Javascript) not allowed
I am trying to use Google App Scripts, to move a bunch of folders from My Drive to a Shared Drive. I have a Google Workspace (paid) account, for business. I'm getting an error that this is not supported, as per below:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed with error: Moving folders into shared drives is not supported.

Below is a copy of the code:
util.gdrive.getParentId = function(fileId)
{
  var options = {
       supportsAllDrives: true,
       supportsTeamDrives: true,
       
       'fields': 'id, parents'
     };
  var result = Drive.Files.get(fileId, options);
  var parentId = result.parents[0];
  return parentId;
}

util.gdrive.moveFolder3 = function (sourceFolderId, destinationFolderId) {
  var sourceFolderParentId = util.gdrive.getParentId(sourceFolderId);
  var resourceUpdate = {

          'fields': 'id, parents',
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          
        };

        
  var mediaData = null;
  var options = {
       supportsAllDrives: true,

       'addParents': destinationFolderId, 
       'removeParents': sourceFolderParentId 
     };
  var updatedFile = Drive.Files.update(resourceUpdate, sourceFolderId, mediaData, options);
  return updatedFile;


}

Is there any possible way how to do this by code? Am I using a wrong method, or is it just plain, not suppoted - no possible way to do this? I need to move a lot of files/folders from MyDrive to Shared Drive, which is next to impossible to do manually. The account I am logged in with should be an admin account, hence I don't think this is an access issue.
Note that it is possible to do it manually via the Web-UI interface - hence it seems that it is technically possible.

I did some testing and confirmed that it's possible to move files from My Drive to Shared Drive. However, when trying to move a folder and its contents, it gives an error similar to what you provided. That being said, it seems that Google's already aware of this matter, so a +1 to it would tell them that you're impacted by the issue. This is the link for the feature request: Allow Drive API (v3) to migrate folders from My Drive into Shared Drives

@Saddles Yeah its folders which are the issue. Considering this feature request has been commented on since 2021, I have my doubts if this will be actually fixed

I totally understand. A workaround that I can think of is to have the script move all the files inside the folders to the root of My Drive, delete the empty folders so that you won't encounter the error, and then put the files over to Shared Drive. I can share the code that I have for this, which also renames the files to have the folder name before, for example: Folder 1_Untitled project.

Recently, I have had several requests about the same situation with you. I created a script for achieving this. When I saw your question and other related questions in Stackoverflow, I thought that when this is published, it might be useful for other users. So, in this answer, I would like to introduce my script.
Issue
In the current stage, when a folder including files and folders is moved from a Google Drive to a shared drive using a script, the following error messages appear.
For Drive API
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Moving folders into shared drives is not supported.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Moving folders into shared drives is not supported.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "teamDrivesFolderMoveInNotSupported"
      }
    ]
  }
}

For Drive service (DriveApp)
Exception: Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item.

This has already been mentioned in the Saddles's comment.
Workaround
In this answer, as a workaround, I created a script for doing the following steps.

Retrieving Folder Structure
Recreating Folder Structure
File Movement
Source Folder Removal

When a Google Apps Script is created from this step, you can see it at my repository.
When a folder is moved between Google Drive except for the shared drive, a simple script can be used as follows.
DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId))

But, as your situation, when a folder is moved from your Google Drive to a sharead drive, the above issue occurs. So, I used the above workaround.
IMPORTANT: Please read this before you test

This script automates moving folders and files within your Google Drive, including those in shared drives. Use caution when running the script, as it will modify your file structure.
For safe testing, create a sample folder and populate it with some files. If you have a large number of folders and files, consider splitting them into smaller groups for individual testing.

Usage
1. Create a Google Apps Script project
In this report, Google Apps Script is used. Of course, the approach introducing this report can also be used in other languages.
Here, in order to test the following sample scripts, please create a standalone Google Apps Script project. Of course, this script can also be used with the container-bound script.
And, please open the script editor of the Google Apps Script project.
2. Install a Google Apps Script library
When I created a script for this, the script was a bit complicated. So, in order to easily use this script, I created it as a Google Apps Script library. Of course, you can see the actual script of this library at my repository.
Please install the library to your Google Apps Script project with the script editor. Ref The project key for installing this library is as follows.
1UEyIfxDTat6GYRFy5iJ3UGj2QpyVuuQI5i-BsOcHDMr8HadIWailwj4k

3. Enable Drive API
This script uses Drive API. So, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. Ref
4. Sample script
After the library is installed and Drive API is enabled, you can test this script. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor installing the library.
Please set the source folder ID and the destination folder ID.
function myFunction() {
  const srcFolderId = "###";
  const dstFolderId = "###";
  MoveFolder.run({ srcFolderId, dstFolderId });
}

When you run the function myFunction, the folder of the folder srcFolderId is moved to the folder dstFolderId.
Note:

If you have no permission to edit the destination folder, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

